# Error when mapping from Entity to DTO or DTO to Entity using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I'm using EntityFramework as a DataLayer and DTO to transfer data between layer. I develop Windows Forms in N-Tier architecture and when I try to mapping from Entity to DTO in BLL:

```
public IEnumerable<CategoryDTO> GetCategoriesPaged(int skip, int take, string name)
{
    var categories = unitOfWork.CategoryRepository.GetCategoriesPaged(skip, take, name);
    var categoriesDTO = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Category>, List<CategoryDTO>>(categories);

    return categoriesDTO;
}
```

I've got this error:
http://s810.photobucket.com/user/sky3913/media/AutoMapperError.png.html

The error said that I missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping. I have registered mapping using profile in this way at UI Layer:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    AutoMapperBusinessConfiguration.Configure();
    AutoMapperWindowsConfiguration.Configure();
    ...
    Application.Run(new frmMain());
}
```

and AutoMapper configuration is in BLL:

```
public class AutoMapperBusinessConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddProfile<EntityToDTOProfile>();
            cfg.AddProfile<DTOToEntityProfile>();
        });
    }
}

public class EntityToDTOProfile : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "EntityToDTOMappings"; }
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryDTO>();
    }
}

public class DTOToEntityProfile : Profile
{
    public override string ProfileName
    {
        get { return "DTOToEntityMappings"; }
    }

    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<CategoryDTO, Category>();
    }
}
```

I've got the same error too when mapping from DTO to Entity.

```
category = Mapper.Map<Category>(categoryDTO);
```

How to solve this?

Comment: instead of `var categoriesDTO = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Category>, List<CategoryDTO>>(categories);` can you try mapping them one at a time in a loop using `var categoryDto = Mapper.Map<CategoryDTO>(category)` ?

Comment: @wal I've got the same error "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping"

Comment: instead of using the profile can you just see what happens if you try creating the mapping prior to the actual map. eg call `Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryDTO>();` then directly after do your mapping; dont map a list that comes back from entity framework; instead loop and map individually.

Comment: I remove the profile, and define Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryDTO>() before do Mapper.Map, and it works. I think because the configuration using profile did not configure correctly. Actually I want to centralize automapper configuration so I'm using profile. Any idea how to achive this in ntier architecture?

Comment: instead of `Mapper.Initialize`have you tried simply `Mapper.AddProfile(new EntityToDTOProfile ())` - it shouldnt matter having looked at the source code but try. also ensure your mapping profile is hit when starting your app

Comment: @wal I've changed Mapper.Initialize and tried Mapper.AddProfile(new EntityToDTOProfile()) and the result is same

Comment: put a breakpoint on your `Configure` method. is it hit ?

Comment: @wal Yes it is hit correctly. I think I found the problem, after call `AutoMapperBusinessConfiguration.Configure();` I call mapping configuration from DTO to ViewModel `AutoMapperWindowsConfiguration.Configure();`. If I remove `AutoMapperWindowsConfiguration.Configure();` it works. So, should I defined in one class or is there a way to configure in separate classes based on its functionality?

Comment: Its because you are using `Mapper.Initialize` multipe times. If you look at the source code for this call it calls `Mapper.Reset()` which means only the last mapping defined will work. so instead simply remove the `Initialize` calls and replace with Mapper.AddProfile< >

Comment: I understand. Thank you very much @wal for directing me to solve this problem. Could you add this as an answer?

Comment: glad you found the issue. answer added :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because you are using `Mapper.Initialize` multiple times. If you look at the source code  it calls `Mapper.Reset()` which means only the last mapping defined will work. so instead simply remove the Initialize calls and replace with `Mapper.AddProfile< >`

Answer (score 2):

Use `AutoMapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` after the `Configure()` calls. If anything fails it will throw an exception with a descriptive text. It should give you more info to debug further.

Comment: Nice info, after call AssertConfigurationIsValid() there are some exceptions mapping, very descriptive. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mapping DTOs to Entities using AutoMapper and EntityFramework

here we have an Entity class Country and an CountryDTO

```
 public class Country
 {
     public int CountryID { get; set; }
     public string ContryName { get; set; }
     public string CountryCode { get; set; }
 }
```

CountryDto

```
 public class CountryDTO
{
   public int CountryID { get; set; }
   public string ContryName { get; set; }
   public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}
```

Create Object of CountryDTO

```
CountryDTO collection=new CountryDTO();
 collection.CountryID =1;
 collection.ContryName ="India";
 collection.CountryCode ="in";

Country model = Convertor.Convert<Country, CountryDTO>(collection);
dbcontext.Countries.Add(model);
dbcontext.SaveChanges();
```

this will work fine for a new Country, the above code will map CountryDTO to Country Entity Object and add new entities to the dbcontext and save the changes.

```
using System.Reflection;
public static TOut Convert<TOut, TIn>(TIn fromRecord) where TOut : new()
 {
  var toRecord = new TOut();
  PropertyInfo[] fromFields = null;
  PropertyInfo[] toFields = null;

  fromFields = typeof(TIn).GetProperties();
  toFields = typeof(TOut).GetProperties();

  foreach (var fromField in fromFields)
   {
    foreach (var toField in toFields)
      {
        if (fromField.Name == toField.Name)
          {
             toField.SetValue(toRecord, fromField.GetValue(fromRecord, null), null);
            break;
          }
      }

  }
return toRecord;
}

public static List<TOut> Convert<TOut, TIn>(List<TIn> fromRecordList) where TOut : new()
 {
  return fromRecordList.Count == 0 ? null : fromRecordList.Select(Convert<TOut, TIn>).ToList();
 }
```

http://bhupendrasinghsaini.blogspot.in/2014/09/convert-enity-framwork-data-in-entity.html